# Disabling talkback for specific application

Tags: android

i have a project to modify android phone for blind people, thus i used android text to speech.

I've managed to create a SMS and phone application using TTS library from http://code.google.com/p/eyes-free/ and use myTTS.speak to speak a text.

the problem comes when i use talkback to speak other application like a launcher, browser etc.
when i use talkback they can speak those app, but when i open my app ( SMS and Phone) there are two sound, first from talkback and from built in myTTS.speak in my app,
how i can disabling talkback only in my app(SMS and Phone)?so the speak only come from my app built in TTS, because i'll need talkback when i open other app

thanx

Answer (score 2):

Instead of disabling or muting TalkBack, you could detect that it is running (by checking all running processes), and mute your app's self-voicing when TalkBack is running. You should of course preserve your app's self-voicing for those messages that TalkBack would not speak.

Alternatively, to keep TalkBack from receiving (and speaking) events from your app you can use the mechanisms discussed [here](http://groups.google.com/group/eyes-free-dev/browse_thread/thread/0cde455c69b22568/).